# Can i use same firebase database for php web application and android mobile application? How?

Tags: php, android, firebase

I want to develop an android mobile application and php web application. So far I have developed the android mobile app with firebase. Is it possible to create a php web application to link to the same firebase database?

Comment: yes possible ...

Comment: Yes you can use it for other platforms as well. Firebase even provides [SDK for android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

Comment: Yes you can use the same database for this